# Adding a new Object to V8 using Torque

Tags: v8

TL;DR: I tried adding a new Object defined exclusively in Torque and use it as a new member for the `Name` class. This resulted in compilation failures due to *function used but never defined* errors, pertaining to a function that **IS** defined in torque-generated files, however for some reason not properly included.

I am unsure how to proceed and trying to just include different combinations of the torque-generated files in the appropriate locations simply led to *redefinition* errors.

**The question**: Is it possible to define a new object and use it in the way I intend to, without adding C++ class definitions (that inherit from the torque-generated classes and so forth) and if yes, where do I seem to be going  wrong. In the following I will describe the steps I took so far:

- Add a `myClass.tq/` file to `src/objects` that includes a definition of my class along the lines of:

```
@export
@generateBodyDescriptors
class MyClass extends HeapObject {
    macro SomeMacro(): Boolean {...}
    macro Set(): void { this.i = 1 }
    i: uint32;
}
```

- Add this file to `BUILD.gn`

I then tried to use this new type to add a member to an existing type (the abstract `Name` type):

- Added a new member in `src/objects/name.tq`
- Included `torque-generated/src/objects/myClass.tq` in `src/objects/name.h`
- `String` inherits from `Name` so i had to modify two "constructors" methods in `src/objects/string.tq` to include the new member
- Changed the expected size of `String` objects in `include/v8-interal.h` to account for the new member
- Added some macros to `Name` that actually use the new member (check if its internal uint is non-zero and set the value to one)

And lastly I added two methods to the String prototype that I defined as javascript builtins, so that I can verify my changes work.

Concretely, the resulting errors complained about the `TorqueGeneratedMyClass::cast(Object)` method being used but never defined. This error results from the `myClass-tq.inc` file. However, the method **is** defined, in the corresponding `myClass-tq-inl.inc` file.

I'm not sure if I described the issue concretely enough, but I'm happy to clarify uncertainties and appreciate every help.

**Edit**:

Complete Changes:

```
// src/objects/myClass.tq
@export
@generateBodyDescriptors
class MyClass extends HeapObject {
    macro IsSet(): Boolean {
        return this.i == 0 ? False : True;
    }
    macro Set(): void { this.i = 1 }
    i: uint32;
}

// src/objects/name.h

@@ -16,6 +17,7 @@
 namespace v8 {
 namespace internal {

+#include "torque-generated/src/objects/taint-tq.inc"
 #include "torque-generated/src/objects/name-tq.inc"

// src/objects/name.tq
@@ -4,7 +4,18 @@

 @abstract
 extern class Name extends PrimitiveHeapObject {
+  macro IsSet(): Boolean {
+    return this.test.IsSet();
+  }
+
+  macro Set(): void {
+    this.test.Set();
+  }
+
+  test: MyClass;
   raw_hash_field: NameHash;

}

// src/objects/string.tq
@@ -135,7 +135,10 @@ macro AllocateNonEmptySeqOneByteString<Iterator: type>(
   dcheck(length != 0 && length <= kStringMaxLength);
   return new SeqOneByteString{
     map: kOneByteStringMap,
+    test: new StringTaint{tainted: 0},
     raw_hash_field: kNameEmptyHashField,
     length: Signed(length),
     chars: ...content
   };
@@ -146,7 +149,10 @@ macro AllocateNonEmptySeqTwoByteString<Iterator: type>(
   dcheck(length > 0 && length <= kStringMaxLength);
   return new SeqTwoByteString{
     map: kStringMap,
+    test: new StringTaint{tainted: 0},
     raw_hash_field: kNameEmptyHashField,
     length: Signed(length),
     chars: ...content
   };

// src/builtins/string-test.tq

namespace string {
    transitioning javascript builtin StringPrototypeIsSet(js-implicit context: NativeContext, receiver: JSAny)(): Boolean {
        const string: String = ToThisString(receiver, 'String.prototype.testIsSet');
        return string.IsSet();
    }

    transitioning javascript builtin StringPrototypeSet(js-implicit context: NativeContext, receiver: JSAny)(): JSAny {
        const string: String = ToThisString(receiver, 'String.prototype.testSet');
        string.Set();

        return Undefined;
    }
}

// src/init/bootstrapper.cc

@@ -2078,6 +2078,10 @@ void Genesis::InitializeGlobal(Handle<JSGlobalObject> global_object,
                           Builtin::kStringPrototypeSup, 0, false);
     SimpleInstallFunction(isolate_, prototype, "startsWith",
                           Builtin::kStringPrototypeStartsWith, 1, false);
+    SimpleInstallFunction(isolate_, prototype, "testSet",
+                          Builtin::kStringPrototypeTaint, 0, true);
+    SimpleInstallFunction(isolate_, prototype, "testIsSet",
+                          Builtin::kStringPrototypeIsTainted, 0, true);
     SimpleInstallFunction(isolate_, prototype, "toString",
                           Builtin::kStringPrototypeToString, 0, true);
     SimpleInstallFunction(isolate_, prototype, "trim",

// BUILD.gn

@@ -1698,6 +1698,7 @@ torque_files = [
   "src/builtins/string-startswith.tq",
   "src/builtins/string-substr.tq",
   "src/builtins/string-substring.tq",
+  "src/builtins/string-test.tq",
   "src/builtins/string-trim.tq",
   "src/builtins/symbol.tq",
   "src/builtins/torque-internal.tq",
@@ -1781,6 +1782,7 @@ torque_files = [
   "src/objects/swiss-hash-table-helpers.tq",
   "src/objects/swiss-name-dictionary.tq",
   "src/objects/synthetic-module.tq",
+  "src/objects/myClass.tq",
   "src/objects/template-objects.tq",
   "src/objects/templates.tq",
   "src/objects/torque-defined-classes.tq",
```

Error:

```
In file included from ../deps/v8/src/objects/name.h:20,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/objects/string.h:15,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/heap/factory.h:25,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/execution/isolate.h:33,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/logging/log.h:16,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/heap/base-space.h:12,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/heap/spaces.h:16,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/heap/marking-visitor.h:13,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/heap/concurrent-marking.h:14,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/heap/concurrent-marking.cc:5:
/home/ccloud/sap_node/out/Release/obj/gen/torque-generated/src/objects/myClass-tq.inc:26:22: warning: inline function ‘static D v8::internal::TorqueGeneratedMyClass<D, P>::cast(v8::internal::Object) [with D = v8::internal::MyClass; P = v8::internal::HeapObject]’ used but never defined
   26 |   V8_INLINE static D cast(Object object);
      |                      ^~~~
/home/ccloud/sap_node/out/Release/obj/gen/torque-generated/src/objects/myClass-tq.inc: In static member function ‘static T v8::internal::ConcurrentMarkingVisitor::Cast(v8::internal::HeapObject) [with T = v8::internal::MyClass]’:
/home/ccloud/sap_node/out/Release/obj/gen/torque-generated/src/objects/myClass-tq.inc:26:22: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘static D v8::internal::TorqueGeneratedMyClass<D, P>::cast(v8::internal::Object) [with D = v8::internal::MyClass; P = v8::internal::HeapObject]’: function body not available
../deps/v8/src/heap/concurrent-marking.cc:103:19: note: called from here
  103 |     return T::cast(object);
      |            ~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~
make[1]: *** [tools/v8_gypfiles/v8_base_without_compiler.target.mk:1000: /home/ccloud/sap_node/out/Release/obj.target/v8_base_without_compiler/deps/v8/src/heap/concurrent-marking.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
In file included from ../deps/v8/src/objects/name.h:20,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/objects/string.h:15,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/heap/factory.h:25,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/execution/isolate.h:33,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/common/ptr-compr-inl.h:10,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/execution/isolate-utils-inl.h:8,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/diagnostics/objects-printer.cc:11:
/home/ccloud/sap_node/out/Release/obj/gen/torque-generated/src/objects/myClass-tq.inc:26:22: warning: inline function ‘static D v8::internal::TorqueGeneratedMyClass<D, P>::cast(v8::internal::Object) [with D = v8::internal::MyClass; P = v8::internal::HeapObject]’ used but never defined
   26 |   V8_INLINE static D cast(Object object);
      |                      ^~~~
/home/ccloud/sap_node/out/Release/obj/gen/torque-generated/src/objects/myClass-tq.inc: In member function ‘void v8::internal::HeapObject::HeapObjectPrint(std::ostream&)’:
/home/ccloud/sap_node/out/Release/obj/gen/torque-generated/src/objects/myClass-tq.inc:26:22: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘static D v8::internal::TorqueGeneratedMyClass<D, P>::cast(v8::internal::Object) [with D = v8::internal::MyClass; P = v8::internal::HeapObject]’: function body not available
../deps/v8/src/diagnostics/objects-printer.cc:216:21: note: called from here
  216 |     Name::cast(*this).Name##Print(os); \
      |                     ^
/home/ccloud/sap_node/out/Release/obj/gen/torque-generated/instance-types.h:637:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘MAKE_TORQUE_CASE’
  637 |   V(MyClass, MY_CLASS_TYPE) /* src/objects/myClass.tq?l=1&c=1 */ \
      |   ^
../deps/v8/src/diagnostics/objects-printer.cc:220:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘TORQUE_INSTANCE_CHECKERS_SINGLE_FULLY_DEFINED’
  220 |       TORQUE_INSTANCE_CHECKERS_SINGLE_FULLY_DEFINED(MAKE_TORQUE_CASE)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from ../deps/v8/src/objects/name.h:20,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/objects/string.h:15,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/heap/factory.h:25,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/execution/isolate.h:33,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/common/ptr-compr-inl.h:10,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/execution/isolate-utils-inl.h:8,
                 from ../deps/v8/src/diagnostics/objects-printer.cc:11:
/home/ccloud/sap_node/out/Release/obj/gen/torque-generated/src/objects/myClass-tq.inc:26:22: error: inlining failed in call to always_inline ‘static D v8::internal::TorqueGeneratedMyClass<D, P>::cast(v8::internal::Object) [with D = v8::internal::MyClass; P = v8::internal::HeapObject]’: function body not available
   26 |   V8_INLINE static D cast(Object object);
      |                      ^~~~
../deps/v8/src/diagnostics/objects-printer.cc:216:21: note: called from here
  216 |     Name::cast(*this).Name##Print(os); \
      |                     ^
/home/ccloud/sap_node/out/Release/obj/gen/torque-generated/instance-types.h:637:3: note: in expansion of macro ‘MAKE_TORQUE_CASE’
  637 |   V(MyClass, MY_CLASS_TYPE) /* src/objects/myClass.tq?l=1&c=1 */ \
      |   ^
../deps/v8/src/diagnostics/objects-printer.cc:220:7: note: in expansion of macro ‘TORQUE_INSTANCE_CHECKERS_SINGLE_FULLY_DEFINED’
  220 |       TORQUE_INSTANCE_CHECKERS_SINGLE_FULLY_DEFINED(MAKE_TORQUE_CASE)
      |       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to define a new object and use it in the way I intend to, without adding C++ class definitions

Yes.

> where do I seem to be going wrong

This part seems suspicious:

> the method **is** defined, in the corresponding myClass-tq-inl.inc file

All generated *.inc files have to be `#include`d somewhere. There's likely some `*.cc` file that needs it (you didn't provide enough details, so I can't tell for sure).

---

A couple of more general points:

- when asking for programming help (anywhere!), provide reproducible code (in this case: your complete patch, not just a prose description of it).
- when asking about compiler errors, provide the complete error message, not just a vague summary like "the errors complained about ...".
- while you are of course free to fork V8 and muck with its internals, a word of caution: such modifications are likely to be very labor-intensive to maintain as you update to newer V8 versions (and you *will* want to update to newer V8 versions, if this isn't just some throwaway experiment). To make your work more future-proof, either attempt to upstream it (which might be difficult in this case, as increasing the size of `Name` objects will be an unpopular proposition, I expect), or use only the public API (which isn't perfectly stable, but *much* more stable than random internals). Of course, the latter won't allow you to modify internally used objects; since you didn't describe your higher-level goal I can't tell whether that's a dealbreaker or whether there could be alternative approaches.

Comment: First of all thanks for the answer, I added all the changes I made and the complete error. Not sure, if that helps. Anyway, the goal is to implement taint tracking, which requires all strings and such to carry taint information.

Comment: That confirms my guess: you'll have to #include myClass-tq-inl.inc wherever it's needed. For a quick'n'dirty approach, you can try including it from name-inl.h, that might be enough. Good luck with your project!